# rebuilding packages and the package manager on debian

Tags: linux, nginx, package, debian, rebuild

This is something that has been bugging me for a while, unable to find any good answers googling, hopefully someone can have a solid answer here.

It's about how to rebuild debian packages and how to maintain them.

First, how would I install NGiNX with enabled non-default modules.  I assume it's as simple as to downloading the package source, editing something, rebuild it, and install it.  But how do you do it, step by step.

Second, once you have a rebuilt package installed, what if a newer version of NGiNX is released, and you want to upgrade it by running a simple "apt-get upgrade" command.  Would it do it or do you have to redownload and rebuild the package? Also, if it doesn't work like that, how do you make it work like that?

Someone please give a clear answer.  THanks so much!

Comment: Besides what http://serverfault.com/questions/65858/how-should-i-create-a-local-fork-of-a-debian-package already offers, I'd add "use version control".  If you have a Quilt package, adding a patch of your own should be quite robust; but if the upstream touches the same code, you may need to regenerate your patch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which changes you want to do on the package,so I can't give you a walktrhough on how to apply those changes,but if you want to rebuild a debian package,you can follow [this guide](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/12/15/howto-to-rebuild-debian-packages/).

As for the apt-get upgrade,I believe it would overwrite your rebuilt package,if the version of the new package is more recent then your rebuilt one.You would probably need to rebuild the new version to keep your changes.